# How are hardware specific bugs and features tested in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

How do kernel developers test changes on very specific hardware? If they don't have that particular type of hardware, how do they figure out where the issue is happening?

Comment: Your question was rather difficult to understand so I made some grammatical changes. Please edit if I have unintentionally changed the meaning of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the kernel developers responsible for writing drivers for a specific piece of hardware also happens to be the tester and someone who owns that piece of hardware.

If that developer comes across a bug (or if people report a bug) on that piece of hardware, he is usually the one that fixes it. It'd be silly to ask someone to fix or maintain a driver for some hardware he does not own.

As to higher level kernel features, here is where the Linux development paradigm comes into play. Linux employs a merge window strategy for releasing since it's unrealistic to ask every developer to test his changes on every single possible combination of hardware and software combinations.

Instead, after a major release, a merge window is opened up for around 2 weeks where developers can push in significant changes, new drivers and features. After the merge window closes, no more patches for new changes are accepted.

During this time where the merge window is closed, developers have a chance to test the newly merged code on their own hardware and report bugs and breakages. Usually, the developer works together with the person that introduced the change to fix the bug. The developer can now send the fix to be included in the next release candidate.

A new release candidate is released roughly weekly. When Linus is happy that most of the bugs introduced this version has been fixed, he makes a major release and the cycle starts again.

In other words, the answer to your question is that they don't. No one developer is responsible for everything nor are they expected to fix problems for other people. A developer is only responsible for the part of the kernel that he maintains.

Answer (score 0):

I do maintain drivers for some hardware which I do not have (and which no other kernel developer has).

Changes in such drivers must be done *very* carefully:

- Sometimes it is possible to test the change on similar hardware that *is* available.
- When an issue was reported by a user, it might be possible to ask this user to test the change, or to find some other user with the same hardware.
- When an actual bug (security related or otherwise) *must* be fixed, the best solution might be to apply the change untested, and hope for the best.
- Otherwise, just don't make the change.